# Pass multiple state values into an input with React

Tags: reactjs, state

Somewhat new to react and having trouble passing multiple state values to an input.

Specifically, state from drop-down menus. I can accomplish this in a p tag by chaining the various state values together.

**This works**

```
   <p> 
    {this.state.one}_
    {this.state.two}_
    {this.state.three}_
    {this.state.four}_
    {this.state.five}
    </p>
```

**This will return**

```
one_two_three_four_five
```

Whenever I try to pass these same values into a single input I get an error.

**This does not work**

```
<label>
  Title:
  <input 
value=
{this.state.one}_
{this.state.two}_
{this.state.three}_
{this.state.four}_
{this.state.five}
 type="text" /> 
</label>
```

How can one pass multiple state values into a single input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template literals with variables :

```
<input 
        value={ `${this.state.one}_${this.state.two}` }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a single expression to the `value` attribute. Change to this:

```
<label>
  Title:
  <input value={`${this.state.one}_
    ${this.state.two}_
    ${this.state.three}_
    ${this.state.four}_
    ${this.state.five}`
 }
 type="text" /> 
</label>
```

Note: this is ES6 string interpolation. The ES5 alternative is the regular string concatenation with "+"